# jQuery toggle visibility of animated elements

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I have a page that's utilizing jQuery navigation buttons that should slide content into view when each is clicked. However, when another button is clicked, I need the currently viewed content to slide back out of view before the new content slides into view.

This is what I've done so far:

```
$("#rules-btn").click(function () {
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = { direction: 'left' };
    var duration = 700;
    $('#rules-pane').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Krebbstar/e6kaV) that shows how it acts now. Can anyone tell me how to hide currently viewed content when another button is clicked? Thanks.

By the way, I'm very new to jQuery...

Answer (score 3):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/e6kaV/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="rules" class="pane-launcher"></div>
<div id="rules-pane" class="pane"></div>
<div id="scenarios" class="pane-launcher"></div>
<div id="scenarios-pane" class="pane"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".pane-launcher").click(function () {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'left' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 700;
    $('.pane.active, #'+this.id+'-pane').toggle(effect, options, duration).toggleClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.pane-launcher{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#000;
    display:block;
}
#rules {
    left:0px;
}
#scenarios {
    left:40px;
}
.pane{
    position:absolute;    
    left: 0;
    height:50px;
    display:none;
    opacity:0.5;
}
#rules-pane {
    top:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#999;
}

#scenarios-pane {
    top:60px;
    width:170px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

**Remember**: instead of dealing with lots of ids, it's better to use classes, both to add styles and event handlers.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. It makes total sense now.